# Connect dbeaver to mysql-server inside vmware machine

Tags: java, mysql, windows, ubuntu, dbeaver

Please help me, I'm try to connect client dbeaver to mysql-server inside vmware ubuntu 20.04.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5IvF.png)]

Ip host client: 172.25.3.65 - Windows
Ip host server : 192.168.11.128 - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Y try edit mysql.cnf:
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3TBy.png)]

And create users with privilges:

```
CREATE USER ctdb@'172.25.3.65' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ctdb_bq.* TO 'ctdb'@'172.25.3.65' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTU4A.png)]

But, when I try connect with dbeaver show this error;

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdkDS.png)]

Comment: Try to avoid posting images where the data could be pasted as text (and formatted). This makes it easier for others to view and help with your query.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
> mysql
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
> mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
> mysql
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And in **Ubuntu** configuring the `ufw` firewall:

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw disable 
sudo ufw enable
```

**IN DBEAVER**

And I can establishing connection with `ssh`.

```
In general options: 
user: root
pass:**
```

and tunel ssh options with credencials to OS.

**Note**: Is important install `openssh` in **Ubuntu** *server* to enable this connection type.